Recently got a Dell PowerEdge R720 but I’m having some problems with the USB ports and the iDRAC
I recently got a free Dell PowerEdge R720 and I'm trying to install Alpine Linux on it, but I’m having some problems with the USB ports and the iDRAC.
Here’s what’s going on:

The USB ports are enabled in the BIOS and work with other devices, but my bootable USB drive isn’t being recognized and is not an option in the boot menu.
I was going to use the iDRAC panel to install the OS, but I can't connect to it. The iDRAC should be at 192.168.1.100, but I can't access it.
It’s not pingable and doesn’t show up on the router’s list of devices.
I tried both the dedicated iDRAC port and the regular network port and changed the network settings, but nothing worked.
When I switch to DHCP, the front LCD shows an IP of 0.0.0.0.

Additional Info:

USB Drive Creation: I used Balena Etcher to create the bootable USB drive, but it didn’t offer a choice of format. I’ve tested both BIOS and UEFI settings (on the server for boot option), but I can’t select UEFI boot options when UEFI is enabled, and neither boot method seems to work.
LED Indicators: All LEDs on the server that I can see are green.

Server Info:

Model: Dell PowerEdge R720
BIOS Version: 2.7.0
System CPLD Version: 103
iDRAC Firmware Version: 2.63.60 (Build 1)
IPM Version: 2.00
iDRAC License: Enterprise
iDRAC Connectivity: I’ve tried both static IP and DHCP configurations. When set to DHCP, the iDRAC displays an IP of 0.0.0.0.

Questions:

How can I fix the iDRAC connectivity issue?
Any tips for booting from USB on this server?


The system came with the license for iDRAC?

How're you connected to the iDRAC? I wonder if connecting directly to the management port, and trying a static IP on the 'client' machine might help. rather than connecting it to a network. Also, I think rufus will create installers that work on both bios and UEFI?
